# Не работает эмулятор Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, avd

Загрузил виртуальное устройство Nexus S, пытаюсь запустить приложение - выдает ошибку:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
> acceleration!
>
> Emulator: emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Текст ошибки - текстом, а не картиной. Кроме этого, вы забыли задать вопрос и попытаться самостоятельно найти решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

*Первый вариант*

**Если у Вас AMD процессор:**

1. Включите виртуализацию  в BIOS
2. Tools > Android > SDK Manager > Other Images

> ARM EABI v7a System Image

или

> ARM 64 v8a System Image

---

*[Есть второй вариант](https://www.genymotion.com/download/) - использовать другой скачанный эмулятор Android. У меня тоже не получались танцы с бубном (у меня AMD A10-7850K) - **мучался, пока не скачал Genymotion и VirtualBox**.*

1. Установить Genymotion и VirtualBox
2. Скачать [плагин](https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/) для Android Studio
3. Подключить плагин можно так: File > Settings > Plugins > Install plugin from disk > Перезагрузить Android Studio
4. Запустить эмулятор и нажать в студии Run App > Выбрать устройство среди подключенных.